# Can you and is it advisable to use the same ssh key for github and gitlab/gitbucket

Tags: git, github, gitlab, ssh-keys

Can you use the same ssh key for different version control hosting services?

And if you can, what are the pros and cons?

**Scenario:** I have ssh keys that I am using on my computer, can I and should I use the same ssh keys with gitlab/gitbucket on the same computer?

Comment: Of course you *can*, the services don't cross-check against each other to tell if a key is in use elsewhere, but as VonC points out, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, it is not advisable: a private key should remain used for only one service, that way you can revoke/change it just for that service.

What you can do is set up a [`~/.ssh/config`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/) file in which you can associate the right private key with the right host, as [explained here](https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/).

Comment: Hey kindly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287059/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-config-file-for-beginners?noredirect=1#comment99187049_56287059