# How to set up an SSH config-file for beginners

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

First I am fairly new to SSH.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285972/can-you-and-is-it-advisable-to-use-the-same-ssh-key-for-github-and-gitlab-gitbuc?noredirect=1#comment99185285_56285972) I have seen the need and benefit of setting up an SSH config file. While I was doing my research I noticed that there is a lot to know on SSH and I also found out that I have been using SSH keys and not the SSH server. I have been using the keys to push my code to my hosted repos.

So now my questions are(I am using windows 10):

1. Can I set up an SSH config file without a tool like openSSH, if so how do I do it?
2. Where in my computer is this config file stored?

Comment: Which ssh client are you using then?

Comment: I just installed git I am using the git terminal

Comment: In Windows `~` is your user's home directory, eg: `C:\Users\username`. Just create the `.ssh/config` file there.

Comment: Basic command-line literacy questions are not really suitable for Stack Overflow; perhaps instead ask over on one of our general-computing sibling sites [apple.se], [unix.se], or [su]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Generally, in Windows machine, the SSH config file stored in the following location:** `/c/Users/PC_USER_NAME/.ssh/`

Just follow the steps in below (if you're using the Git Bash):

1. Go to the .ssh directory `/c/Users/PC_USER_NAME/.ssh/`, click right mouse button and choose "Git Bash Here"
2. Create a file named "config" with the following command:

```
touch config
```

3. Now open the config file with the command:

```
nano config
```

4. Now write the following lines inside the config file

Let's assume you've created two files named `id_rsa_hub` for Github and `id_rsa_lab` for GitLab

```
# GITHUB
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hub

# GITLAB
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lab
```

Comment: this doesn't work on Windows 10, it creates the file with the incorrect ownership and/or permissions

Comment: try to run your command prompt as administrator - **Run as administrator**

Comment: This works for ubuntu resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

By default, your `%HOME%` will be your `%USERPROFILE%`

To create new keys, make sure to add to your environment variables:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

That way, you will have all the commands you need, including `ssh-keygen`, on Windows 10, right from any CMD session (without even opening a `git bash` session).

To create a new SSH key, try first to use an SSH key without passphrase, and make sure to create it [with the legacy format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309) in a CMD session (not git bash):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\myNewKey
```

'`myNewKey`': no extension; no '`.xxx`'.
(The `-m PEM` is for producing the legacy format, because not all remote servers are able to understand then new OPENSSH format)

Then add your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file, to associate your new key to your service (in which you will have registered your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\myNewKey.pub` public key)

See "[Multiple Github Accounts With Git In Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274407/6309)" for an concrete example, as in:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\github_key
```

Then, in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`:

```
Host gh
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_key
```

That way, you can replace the remote URL of GitHub repository with:

```
gh:<yourGitHubUser>/<yourGitHubRepo>
```

Comment: Can't keys and config be saved under C:\ProgramData\ssh\?

Comment: @motorbaby not by default, as SSH looks for "`HOME`", which, on Windows, is `%USERPROFILE%`. I suppose the config file itself (which, again, must be in HOME: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/) can then refer to public/private keys which can be stored anywhere you want.

Comment: im in linux. is it necessory to add "User' in config file, can you share any kind of doc to check more about config files

Comment: @legacy Adding User is a best practice, to avoid repeating said user in the SSH URL. See more at https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/, and https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/