# SSH Connectivity to Heroku account fails

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, ssh-keys

Trying to configure Herokugit, accepted the default key (id_rsa) as the public key, changed the permissions to 600 as it complained its not secure. Now when i try to validate the ssh connection I get invalid file format error.

```
[coderhub@Coderhub-mac heroku]$ssh -v git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/coderhub/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/coderhub/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for heroku.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: Authenticating to heroku.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:8tF0wX2WquK45aGKs/Bh1dKmBXH08vxUe0VCJJWOA/o
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/coderhub/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:suGiIhQN6QphoPJwM4YecZDiTRjNZIPHh46ur58TbvA explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:suGiIhQN6QphoPJwM4YecZDiTRjNZIPHh46ur58TbvA explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:suGiIhQN6QphoPJwM4YecZDiTRjNZIPHh46ur58TbvA explicit
**Load key "/Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format**
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@heroku.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: "Load key "/Users/coderhub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format"—your public key is clearly invalid. How did you create it?

Comment: $ssh-keygen -t rsa

Answer (score 0):

It could be a [SSH key format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309).

Try a regenerate it with the old PEM format (64 char wide in the private key id_rsa) instead of the new OpenSSH one (70 char wide)

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P ""
```

(override your existing keys -- if you don't use it anywhere else --, and register the public one on Heroku)

---

As commented, double-check your `/Users/coderhub/.ssh/config` content:

The `IdentityFile` line in the `heroku.com` entry should reference the private key `id_rsa`, *not* the public key `id_rsa.pub`.
I detailed it in "[Unable to ssh using git config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57917551/6309)".

Comment: On what OS are you on? What is the version of ssh? ssh-keygen?

Comment: Mac OS Mojave 10.14  SSH-OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

Comment: @Vikram OK so the format is relevant. Did you register the public key on Heroku side? (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

Comment: I suspect a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57917551/7976758

Comment: @Vikram Can you check your /Users/coderhub/.ssh/config content? I have edited the answer.

Comment: @phd Good point, I have edited the answer accordingly and notified the OP.