# Git clone on windows : git@github.com is not a git command

Tags: windows, git, ssh, clone

I'm trying to clone a repository the ssh way from github and another form gitlab

I'm on windows EDIT : with Git v 2.29.2.2

I'm getting the following error, which I do not understand from what it is coming from :

```
$ git clone git@github.com:math-gallou/AI21_TPs.git
Cloning into 'AI21_TPs'...
git: 'git@github.com' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I also tried :

```
$ git clone "ssh://git@github.com:math-gallou/AI21_TPs.git"
```

and

```
$ git clone ssh://git@github.com:math-gallou/AI21_TPs.git
```

But the same exact error comes out.

When I do the `ssh -v git@github.com` I can connect with success.

So what did I miss ?

Comment: What version of Git-for-Windows do you have installed?

Comment: Hint (perhaps of no help, but anyway): for `ssh://` URLs the syntax is slightly different: `git clone ssh://git@github.com/math-gallou/AI21_TPs.git` (slash `/` instead of colon `:`). See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are trying the ssh:// syntax, then the URL would be:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/math-gallou/AI21_TPs.git
                            ^^^ /, not :
```

Second, check if you have a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file with a `github.com` Host entry in it, whose content might be incorrect or mis-interpreted.

Comment: So I first tried the syntax you gave me, but the exact same error still shows.
Second, I do not have this config file, ima look for what it is and what it should contain

Comment: @mathoug OK, how about the config file?

Comment: hi @VonC. I did the config file following this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287059/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-config-file-for-beginners. It changes absolutely nothing. With a friend, we are thinking of a weird alias somewhere somehow ? But I tried to clean my git install (deleting and reinstalling everything) and it's still the same ... :/

Comment: @mathoug Can you try with a simplified PATH? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835684/6309)

Comment: It's worse haha, now I get `bash: git: command not found`

Comment: @mathoug I promise you, a simplified PATH is made to reference git, so double-check your PATH. Make sure `GH` is pointing to your Git installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I defined system environment variable GIT_SSH to use openssh I installed, and then git is broken and I got `git: 'git@github.com' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`.

After deleting system environment variable GIT_SSH everything works again.

Then I tried to define **user** environment variable GIT_SSH and restart system (I didn't restart system in previous try), somehow now my git works correctly with openssh I installed. I don't know which part is wrong in my previous try but I decide not to waste more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Update your git maybe help you! I solved the problem by using `git update`.