# How can I programmatically git clone in c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, git

Hi I want to git clone into my current project folder in c# without using any external nuget packages.

I am looking at System.Diagnostics but am not sure how to implement this.

Any advice?

`

```
ProcessStartInfo gitInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process gitProcess = new Process();
gitInfo.Arguments = "git clone";
gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = ?
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run git commands from a C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167387/run-git-commands-from-a-c-sharp-function)

Comment: @Chetan that works but how can I clone it into the current directory rather than currentDirectory/bin/Releases/ ?

Comment: Can you share the code which is now working for you?

Comment: 2 possibilities: 1.Git clone accept a directory as argument where to clone to 2. You could fill the WorkingDirectory property but git clone command will create a sub folder and will clone into it (except if you pass '.' as path argument to the command. See 1.)

Comment: @Philippe how can I set git commands and WorkingDirectory for a Process? I a currently doing Process.start("git", "git clone")

Comment: @Sona Put everything in an answer...

Answer (score 2):

The 3 options:

1. Don't let git create the repo folder (by specifying it in the command line):

```
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "git",
            Arguments = "clone https://repo/url c:/target/path/for/repo",
        }
    };
    process.Start();
```

equivalent also to:

```
    Process.start("git", "clone https://repo/url c:/target/path/for/repo");
```

But if you want to specify the working directory, you have to use `ProcessStartInfo` class.

1.bis. Don't let git create the repo folder (by using the current working directory `.` so you have to fill the `WorkingDirectory` property):

```
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "git",
            Arguments = "clone https://repo/url .",
            WorkingDirectory = "c:/target/path/for/repo",
        }
    };
    process.Start();
```

2. Let git create the repo folder in the working directory folder provided:

```
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "git",
            Arguments = "clone https://repo/url",
            WorkingDirectory = "c:/target/path/for/repo",
        }
    };
    process.Start();
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm now facing the issue here when my URL is ssh://git@github.com/repo and I also tried git@github.con/repo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061142/git-clone-on-windows-gitgithub-com-is-not-a-git-command

Comment: @Sona Difficult to say because there are typos and you don't provide the real data. The uri should be something like `git@github.com/account/repo_name`. But try to find the exact command line in a shell running successfully before putting it in your source code...